# Text data from clipboard event is empty for paste events done via Apple Universal Clipboard

Tags: ios, reactjs, macos, google-chrome, react-otp-input

I was trying out `react-otp-input` and during testing, I copied the OTP I received via email from my iPhone, and pasted it on the OTP Input (React application, in dev mode, running on Chrome 121.0.6167.139 (Official Build) (arm64), Apple M2 Chip).

But the OTP was not pasted.

So I went on to try the same with an ordinary HTML  element, which succeeded, but when I tried to access the text from the Clipboard event as follows

```
<input onPaste={(e) => console.log(e.clipboardData.getData("text"))} />
```

The result was an empty string, as follows

[image: Image of the console where the clipboard event's getData was logged]

I researched quite a bit, but found nothing of much use. I would appreciate any knowledge on this (explanation, workaround etc.). Thanks in advance.